# Alternate Proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am following Folland’s Measure Theory book, and it contains a proof for the MCT that uses the fact that the integral of a simple function induces a measure, and here is my proof without that fact.

**Statement of MCT:**

If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^+$ such that $f_j\leq f_{j+1}$ for all $j$,, and $f = \lim f_n$, then $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.

---

Obviously $f$ is $L^+$ since its the countable supremum of $f_n$. So it makes sense to write $\int f$

The first part of the proof, we show that $\lim \int f_n\leq \int f$ with

$$
0\leq f_1\leq\cdots\leq f\implies0\leq\int f_1\leq\cdots\leq\int f_n\leq\int f
$$

So $\int f$ is a upper bound for the increasing sequence, and $\lim\int f_n\leq\int f$.

We now wish to show the reverse inequality. Since $f=\sup f_n$, pointwise, then for every $\alpha\in(0,1)$, and for every point $p\in X$, there exists a $f_n$ such that $\alpha f(p)\leq f_n(p)$. Since the integral of $f$ is just the supremum over its lesser simple functions $0\leq\phi\leq f$, then

$$
\alpha\phi(p)\leq f_n(p)\quad\forall p\in X
$$

Then, for this fixed $\alpha$, we can choose the supremum over all the $n_p$, then we obtain the pointwise everywhere inequality.

$$
\forall n\geq n_p,\quad \alpha\phi\leq f_n
$$

Then by monotonicity of the integral shown in earlier pages

$$
\int\alpha\phi\leq\int f_n\implies\alpha\int\phi\leq\sup_{n\geq n_p}\int f_n = \lim\int f_n
$$

Then $\lim\int f_n$ is now an upper bound for the integral of $f$’s lesser simple functions, where $\phi\leq f$, so $\int f\leq\lim\int f_n$.

---

**Folland’s Proof:**

The first is the same as above.

To prove $\int f\leq \lim\int f_n$, he uses a

$$
E_n = \{x:f_n(x)\geq\alpha\phi\}
$$

So this sequence of sets is increasing has a union of X, and

$$
\int_{E_n}\alpha\phi\leq\int_{E_n}f_n\leq\int f_n
$$

Then continuity from below gives

$$
\int\alpha\phi\leq\lim\int f_n
$$

This this holds for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$, then this implies

$$
\int f\leq\lim\int f_n
$$

Comment: What are the "Simps"?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The simple functions that are less than f, sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks. I kind of imagined that, but it is easier to read now. So, what is your question? You mention those $E_n$ but later they seem to disappear from the proof

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am not sure if the construct of $E_n$ is necessary. I have included the proof from Folland’s book. Thank you!

Comment: "Then, for this fixed $\alpha$, we can choose the supremum over all the $n_p$". I'm not so sure about that. What if the sup is $\infty$? It's true that for every $\alpha$ there exist an $n_p$ such that $\alpha f(p) \le f_{n_p}(p)$, but how can we be sure that the supremum is finite?

Comment: @blundered_bishop Thank you so much!